# How to randomly delete 10% of attributes values from a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, classification

I have a dataset that has 30 columns. The last column is the target variable in classification.

I need to delete randomly 10% of attributes values. So 10% values from columns 0-29 should be NA.
I also want the data deletion to occur at random i.e. I do not want all columns to have the same deletion percentage.
I require all columns to have a different percentage of deletion. But as a whole, all columns taken together should make up the 10% deleted from the original attribute values.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might be what you're looking for.

```py
import numpy as np

# get dimensions of df
nrows, ncols = len(df.index), 30          

volume = nrows * ncols                    # total number of entries in df
volume_to_be_nan = int(volume * 0.1)      # number of entries to turn to NaN (10 %)

# randomly generate index locations for the new NaNs
indices = np.random.randint(volume, size=volume_to_be_nan)
row_indices = indices % nrows
col_indices = (indices / nrows).astype(int)

# assign NaN to each of the indices in df
for ri, ci in zip(row_indices, col_indices):
  df.iloc[ri, ci] = np.nan
```

---

For example, if `df` is:

```
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
0  19  52  65  85  76  79  99  85  53  20  35   2  66  58  51  56  63  46   0  63  14  27  79  45  30  83  35  32  45  16
1  37  16  75  28  23  77  19  99  34  70  31  74  59  85  90  83  85   2  16  12   6  18   2  16  42  95  54   4  57  23
2  54  54  99  96  64  43  65  17  72  82  19  26  10  64  82  18  72  53  49  76  90  29   6  40  80  57  48  60  75  17
3  57  33  82  28  14  29   2  69   4  67  23  87  31  34  12  86  74  67  32  69  43  19  63   6  78  31  12  16  60  60
4  10  82  26  62  22  21  37  17  33  20  40  93  50  75  24  91  41  79  56  24   5  89  95  59  80  36  23  38  41  79
```

Then the above code returns `df` to be:

```
     0     1   2     3   4     5   6   7     8   9   10  11    12    13    14    15  16  17    18  19  20  21  22  23    24  25  26  27    28  29
0   NaN  52.0  65  85.0  76  79.0  99  85  53.0  20  35   2   NaN  58.0  51.0  56.0  63  46   0.0  63  14  27  79  45  30.0  83  35  32   NaN  16
1  37.0   NaN  75  28.0  23  77.0  19  99  34.0  70  31  74  59.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  85   2  16.0  12   6  18   2  16  42.0  95  54   4  57.0  23
2  54.0  54.0  99  96.0  64   NaN  65  17  72.0  82  19  26  10.0  64.0  82.0  18.0  72  53   NaN  76  90  29   6  40  80.0  57  48  60   NaN  17
3  57.0  33.0  82  28.0  14   NaN   2  69   NaN  67  23  87   NaN  34.0  12.0  86.0  74  67  32.0  69  43  19  63   6   NaN  31  12  16  60.0  60
4  10.0  82.0  26   NaN  22  21.0  37  17  33.0  20  40  93  50.0  75.0  24.0  91.0  41  79  56.0  24   5  89  95  59  80.0  36  23  38  41.0  79
```

Here, the total number of entries is 150, and the total number of NaNs, distributed randomly across the dataframe, is 15 (which is 10% of 150).

Answer (score 1):

Surely Jaeden's solution works, but you can get the desired result without complicated programming by using pandas functions. Basically you need to melt() all columns to one column; then take the desired amount of rows randomly; and finally pivot() to the original dataframe shape. Good to check the amount of nans at the end to be sure that it all worked as supposed.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,99,size=(4, 30)),columns=list(range(0,30)))

df = df.reset_index()
df_onecolumn = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['index'])
df_sampled = df_onecolumn.sample(frac=0.9).reset_index(drop=True)
df_fraction = df_sampled.pivot(index='index', columns='variable', values='value')

df_fraction.isna().sum().sum()
```